# How to use .Contains and ToLower in Linq query in MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, contains

MongoDB C# Linq

How to use .contains and ToLower in Linq query?

```
 List<string> emailAddress = criteriaEmailAddress.ToLower().Split(',').ToList();
 return new Specification<UserProfiles>(r => emailAddress.Contains(r.EmailAddress.ToLower()));
```

**Exception**

> Unsupported filter:
>   Contains(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])).

Comment: a long shot.... but how about converting all the emails to lowercase first, and also try using a string[] instead of a List<string>

Comment: yeah, at  the end have to use that, but that case can also be needed for Firstname, Lastname... etc

Comment: anyone got answer to this? I am stuggling with the same problem.    var t = await (Collection.AsQueryable<User>().Where(p => p.Email != null &&
                   emailList.Contains(p.Email.ToLower())).ToListAsync());  -> Unsupported filter: Contains(value(System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String])).